# Discord.js error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined` when I start up my bot.

This is the code I need help with, the error is in the 2nd line:

```
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("768590991601958933");
const ReactionChannel = guild.channels.cache.get("768590992294150157");
```

And here is the rest of my code, it does not include the code for when someone uses a command (because if I included EVERYTHING then this would be like 160 lines long) in case that helps:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
const config = require("./config.json");

const prefix = config.prefix;

const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("768590991601958933");
const ReactionChannel = guild.channels.cache.get("768590992294150157");

const fs = require('fs');
const { on } = require('process');

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)

    bot.commands.set(command.name, command)
}



bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('LegacyBot is Online!');
    bot.user.setActivity('Coming to the Legacy discord soon!', {type: 'PLAYING'})
});
bot.on('error', () => {
    console.error
})

bot.login(config.token);
```

Comment: If `channels` in undefined, it's pretty clear `const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("768590991601958933");` failed or didn't return what you expected.

Comment: Just tested it, you're right, guild is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Look at the [example here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/#example-usage). See how `client` is listening for a ready event? `bot.on('ready', () => { ...});` should wrap `bot.guilds.cache.get`, otherwise `bot` isn't ready yet.

Comment: Oh my god, I put it in the "ready" part of my code and it works. thank you so much, I would have never found that out without your help.